# Can ghostwriting be listed on the resume?

Tags: subcontracting, resume

I have several health care and science articles that were published in peer-reviewed journals that I wrote or copy edited under contract or as part of my employment at an academic medical center. I am not listed or acknowledged as an author on any of them.

Is it ethical to cite these pieces either on my resume/CV or in cover letters to prospective clients?

(I have no compunction about sharing in face-to-face meeting—should I?)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most straightforward approach would be to follow-up with the various groups you worked with and get explicit permission to reference the articles in your job hunting efforts. While you're at it, you may also want to ask for them to be a client reference.

E.g. speak with them over the phone in person & then follow-up with a confirmation email where you request that they confirm. "Hello , thank you for speaking with me. I wanted to formally confirm that you are comfortable with me sharing my involvement in the  with future employers. Your confirmation reply would be greatly appreciated."